# How to undo Mark goal run as ignored in Eclipse build in Eclipse preferences?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I mistakenly clicked the *"Mark goal run as ignored in Eclipse build in Eclipse preferences (experimental)"*:

[image]

Where/How do I undo this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

m2e uses a file `YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org2.eclipse.m2e.core/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` to store the global lifecycle mappings.

You could manually open this file and remove the corresponding entries. After that you should reload the global lifecycle mappings using the 'reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata' in window > preferences > maven > lifecycle mappings. But you could also edit the file while Eclipse isn't running. In this case you don't have to reload anything.

If you have only added one ignore then you can delete the file completely (maybe make a backup somewhere just to be safe). If you want to remove one but leave the others then take everything between <pluginExecution> and </pluginExecution> for your choice.

I hope this helps a bit. :)

Comment: Yes, this `lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` is right in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core`. Thanks.

Comment: And reloading the global lifecycle mappings in Eclipse goes like that: `Window` > `Preferences` > `Maven` > `Lifecycle Mappings` > `Reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata` (**button**)

Answer (score 0):

I Know i am answering the question quite late, But i have the issue in the new version and it will be useful for the developer. 
Since this plugin configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. Even though if you want to remove the changes then there will be new plugin will be added in the pluginManagement
with below groupID and artifactID

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
<artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
```

With Maven goal as below

```
<goals>
        <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
</goals>
```